# Sails.js sockets. Good and bad sides. Difference with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

So I am learning Sails.js at the moment and more specifically the integrated socket functionality of the framework. I do like the framework because it is very good for building APIs. 
My question is can you give me some comparison between socket.io and the sails sockets. I mean good and bad sides and is it worth it to learn the sails sockets or I should just use socket.io? Can I use socket.io in sails is another question. I didn't find any tutorials for Sails.js sockets and I am very confused. Also I'm new to sockets so if you can explain like for a beginner.

Comment: "My question is can you give me some comparison between socket.io and the sails sockets. I mean good and bad sides and is it worth it to learn the sails sockets or I should just use socket.io? Can I use socket.io in sails is another question."  *Each one* of these questions is far too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sails.js sockets use socket.io under the hood](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.sockets?q=overview). They are merely a "lightweight wrapper" around socket.io connections.

Comment: So why the [Socket Client](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js) doesn't have  emit functionality and how can I define namespaces like in socket.io?

Comment: @HristoEnev, that comment would be great a separate question - it's specific and warrants its own discussion and answer.